# Resize blob image without creating tmp file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I have a scenario where i need to resize thousands of images. I am using [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) to do this.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.read(<blob>)
image.resize "100x100"
Image.create(:img => image.to_blob)
```

But the above code takes too long to process large number of images since it creates a tmp image file for each image it processes.

Is there a way to resize the image without creating the tmp file? I am also open to suggestions on other libraries that can speed up the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using convert command available from imagemagic directly on the image as :

```
`convert source.jpg -resize 120x120 thumbnail.jpg`
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I don't have the image as file. I have the image stored in database as blob and i want the resized image to be stored again in the database. There is too much overhead in MiniMagick creating the tmp file.

Comment: Its not a good practice to store thousand of images in database. Try using http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip or http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads.

Comment: I understand that. But its an external data source which I don't have control over.